# In a line integral over region R enclosing a singularity, how to calculate integral over the singularity without using a limit (or is limit implicit)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, greens-theorem

I have a question about a particular portion of my multivariable calculus book in the chapter on Green's Theorem.

**Let me first set the theory up. If you want to jump to the question it is further below:**

Here is the version of Green's Theorem that is being used:

> Let C be a positively oriented piecewise-smooth simple closed curve
> that bounds the region R in the plane. Suppose that the functions
> $P(x,y)$ and $Q(x,y)$ have continuous first-order partial derivatives
> on R. Then $$\oint_C Pdx + Qdy=\int \int_R (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y})dA $$

This theorem at this point in the exposition of the book is valid for regions that can be divided into subregions that are both vertically and horizontally simple.

Now take a region R with boundaries that consist of two simply closed curves, ie a region R with a hole in it, an annular region R for example:

[image] [image]

We know that $$\int \int_R (\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y})dA = \oint_C Pdx + Qdy = \oint_{C_1} Pdx + Qdy + \oint_{C_2} Pdx + Qdy$$

We get this because when we calculate the line integrals for the curve around $R_1$ and then do the same for the curve around $R_2$, the portions with the arrows cancel out. We are left with a line integral over the outer portion of $C$, ie $C_1$, plus a line integral over the inner portion of $C$, ie $C_2$.

**My question refers to the following problem: calculate** $$\oint_C \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy$$

**where C is a positively oriented piecewise-smooth simple closed curve that encloses the origin $(0,0)$**

[image]

First thing we note is that $$P = \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$$ $$Q = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$ and we have that $$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 0$$ everywhere except at the origin. Using Green's Theorem, this means that $$\oint_C Pdx +Qdy = 0$$ for any C not enclosing the origin.

But our $C$ does enclose the origin. So how do we calculate the line integral in this case? We enclose the origin in a small circle of radius a, such that the circle is contained within our region R (as in the picture above). We parametrize the circle as $$x=a \cos t, y = a \sin t, 0 \leq t \leq 2 \pi$$ which is a counterclockwise orientation by the way (this is the reason for the negative sign in the following expression).

$$\oint_C \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy - \oint_{C_a} \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy = \int \int_R 0 dA = 0$$

$$\implies \oint_C \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy = \oint_{C_a} \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}dx + \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}dy$$

**Finally, the question**

The book goes ahead and calculates the integral on the right side, ie over $C_a$. This is equal to $2 \pi$. Why are we allowed to calculate this integral without somehow taking some sort of limit because we have a singularity at the origin. Ie, the vector field is not defined at $(0,0)$. The book calculates the integral by changing coordinates to polar coordinates, no limit is taken, and in polar coordinates there is no singularity anymore. **Don't we have to take some sort of limit as $a$ goes to zero?**

My experience with this so far is with single-variable calculus where we would need to integrate from say $a$ to 1, and take the limit as $a$ goes to $0^{+}$.